# Meteor with DynamoDB

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, meteor, amazon-dynamodb, database

I have my meteor application running in amazons cloud, and got the question if it can use dynamoDB.

I search the web but could find anything about meteor & dynamoDB together. So the question is, can meteor use dynamoDB instead of mongodb ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible but very difficult!

Meteor works by having 'minimongo' on the browser client and 'proper mongo' on the server. This then allows it to keep track of changes on the client side and the server side.

There's also some really useful bits where the server pays attention to changes to the serverdb in real time using Mongodb's Oplog - a function a bit like SQL triggers.

You'll therefore have lots of effort finding how to tweak meteor to take DynamoDB which will then result in a version of Meteor that doesn't have the same functionality (live udpates from the server).

Won't be fun!

Answer (score 1):

There is a package for this. I have only tried Cloudant setup, but if it works there is should work with DynamoDB.

https://github.com/ccorcos/meteor-any-db

Simply add this package to your project:

meteor add ccorcos:any-db

Rather than have a mini-database on the client, we simply have a subscription-cursor object that represents the results of a server-side query.

Answer (score -3):

If you are already on aws then you can definitely use DynamoDB. Meteor is a pure JS platform and DynamoDB does have support for JavaScript. Check out this link:
[DynamoDB Getting Started](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStartedBeforeYouBegin.html)

Comment: I hoped that there was a package for this, meaning the only thing I needed to do to switch my app to dynamoDB was: `$> meteor install dynamoDB` :) Something like that!

Comment: Already being on AWS isn't relevant and no you can't use dynamo DB even though meteor is pure JS.